# How to pull Check Point Logs from a Check Point Device

Tags: c, client, checkpoint

What I need to do is that,

I need to **pull** the **Check Point Logs** from a **Check Point device**.

I have read that, in order to accomplish this, we have following things,

The **OPSEC LEA** (Log Export API) provides the ability to pull logs from a Check Point device   based on the **OPSEC SDK**. OPSEC LEA listens on port tcp/18184 on the device (**OPSEC LEA Server**)   which will contain your logs. Your OPSEC LEA Client will then connect into 18184 and pull the logs.

So in order to run a LEA server,  I installed a **Check Point R75.20** on my VirtualBox. **I dont know how to run the OPSEC LEA server** on the Check Point R75.20 platform. I have read the documentation for R75.20 as well but could not get a hint on running the server.

Now after I run the lea-server, **isn't it the OPSEC SDK that I will use to write an OPSEC LEA CLient**?

Thanks.

Comment: The lea server is a part of the fwd process.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want the [Opsec SDK found here](http://www.opsec.com/cp_products/90.htm#sdk).

You could also use the [fw1-loggrabber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fw1-loggrabber/) which is probably a LOT easier.